# Not showing data in console.log from pusher

Tags: jquery, laravel, pusher, laravel-5.8

Trying to show data in `console.log` from **pusher**. I am using **laravel 5.8**.

`app.js` file has below code:

```js
let userId = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="user-id"]').content;
Echo.private('App.User.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
    });
```

Error is below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null

I also added CFRS token and Auth:User with id as following in my blade:

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <mete name="user-id" content="{{Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id: ''}}"
```

Comment: Make sure you receive 200 status code from a backend. Are you sure? can you add your response from the backend? You can check into network tab

Comment: Yes I am getting 200 status in `Network` tab. @bhavinjr

Comment: Why did you deleted answer? @bhavinjr

Comment: You can check updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Make sure you have you get correct Id using

```
let userId = document.querySelector('meta[name="user-id"]').content;
```

```
Echo.private('users.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log('received');
        console.log(notification);
    });
```

Make sure you have same channel route

```
Broadcast::channel('users.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id; // it should be true (return true)
});
```

**Suggest**

You can enable global console log from pusher using

```
Pusher.log = function(message) {
    window.console.log(message)
};
```

That can log every pusher event. It will help while developing

Comment: actually, i did not created broadcast channel. I dont know how to create it. I just trying to get data into console.log from pusher.

Comment: You can go with this tutorial https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/

Comment: Actually, I just trying to make notification with laravel echo and pusher. if you dont mind, we can move on chat. @bhavinjr

Answer (score 2):

> spelling mistake here i think

change **mete** to **meta** `(tag name is a not a proper)`

```
 <meta name="user-id" content="{{Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id: ''}}" />
```

**and use without head**

```
let userId = document.querySelector('meta[name="user-id"]').content;
console.log("user Id"+userId);
Echo.private('App.User.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
       console.log(notification.type);
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `app.js:38378 POST http://localhost/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @KINNARI tell u `broadcasting/auth` api not found so add or check  in your web.php

Comment: Actually, I did not created any `broadcasting` but I am trying get data from Pusher. I have created php artisan make:notification .